# Database Generated by EF5 Not Creating Join Table When There are Multiple Relationships

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, entity-framework-5

I have a User and an Organization class. They look like this

```
public class User
{
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Organization> Organizations { get; set; }
}

public class Organization : EntityBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

And both inherit from an EntityBase class to get common fields like Id and created/updated tracking.

```
public abstract class EntityBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }
    public virtual User UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

As denoted by the ICollection properties on both, there should be a many-to-many relation. However when my database is autogenerated I get incorrect foreign keys added to my tables
[image: Incorrect mapping of Organization and User tables]

If I change the CreatedBy and UpdatedBy to be strings instead of User properties I get a join table, which is what I was looking for.
[image: Correct database generation]

Is this a matter of Entity Framework simply being confused and I need to supply many-to-many configuration in the using fluent mappings, or have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple relationships you need to configure them manually by fluent API or using attributes,

> Note:If you have multiple relationships between the same types (for
>   example, suppose you define the Person and Book classes, where the
>   Person class contains the ReviewedBooks and AuthoredBooks navigation
>   properties and the Book class contains the Author and Reviewer
>   navigation properties) you need to manually configure the
>   relationships by using Data Annotations or the fluent API

[Here is the article from Microsoft.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx)